# Cast generic parameter to IComparable<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic function that checks if given arguments are IComparable and if they are call an appropriate method. But I do not get the code compiled.

I get this message:

```
  [CS0311] The type 'System.IComparable<T>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' 
  in the generic type or method 'ValueObjectConformanceTestHelper.CheckComparable<T>(T, T, T)'. 
  There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.IComparable<T>' 
  to 'System.IComparable<System.IComparable<T>>'.
```

This is the code:

```
void CheckComparable<C>(C a, C b) 
    where C : IComparable<C>
{
   a.CompareTo(b).Should().BePositive();
   b.CompareTo(a).Should().BeNegative();
}

void CheckConformance<T>(T a, T b)
{
    if (a is IComparable<T> aComp && b is IComparable<T> bComp)
    {
        this.CheckComparable(aComp, bComp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `void CheckComparable<T>(IComparable<T> value) {...}`? You want `value` be `IComparable<T>` which you pass in `CheckConformance<T>`

Comment: The type checks aren't needed because `T` is already constrained to implement `IComparable<>`. The compiler will refuse to compile code that passes other types to `CheckConformance`

Comment: the T in CheckConformance is a different to the T in CheckComparable. I now renamed i to reflect this.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: maybe i had simplified my example code too much. I cannot change the argument to IComparable<T>, since the argument of CompareTo is of type T. I have updated the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, we can put something like this:

```
// We want a be comparable with with b
void CheckComparable<C>(IComparable<C> a, C b) {
  a.CompareTo(b); // call this here
}

void CheckConformance<T>(T a, T b) {
  if (a is IComparable<T> aComp) {
    CheckComparable<T>(aComp, b);
  }
}
```

However, it looks weird and unreadable. Why not pass `IComparer<T>`?

```
void CheckComparable<C>(C a, C b, IComparer<C> comparer = default) {
  // If no explicit comparer is provided, we get default one:
  // It will be .CompareTo based in case C implements IComparable<C> 
  comparer ??= Comparer<C>.Default;

  // C can't be compared with itself by default and no comparer provided
  // So, we move test here from CheckConformance
  if (comparer is null)
    return;

  // Slightly modified syntax here: comparer instead of CompareTo
  comparer.Compare(a, b); // call this here
}

void CheckConformance<T>(T a, T b) {
  // No check required here
  CheckComparable(a, b);
}
```

Comment: I do not have a comparer. i just want to call the method if the object implements the correct interface.

Comment: with your first solution I can call a.CompareTo(b), but I cannot call b.CompareTo(a)

Comment: @codymanix: Yes, that's why I've extracted `comparer` as a parameter (we can compare whatever we want with it); the main problem with `IComparable<C>` is that if  `aComp` implements `IComparable<C>` it doesn't necessary of type `C` (strange, but possible: `class MyClass : IComparable<MyOtherClass> {...}`).